# ASP.NET Core: Validate Individual Dynamic String Input Fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, asp.net-core, razor-pages

The App: It is fed an order #, and the part ID, part #, and quantity for each part are displayed (so 3 input fields per line, per part). All those values appear as input fields that can be modified. In the PageModel, I store all those values in Lists and then iterate through them to find ones that have been modified. If I find modifications, I update the appropriate parts of the database. The app is to be used 100% in-house by people who know what they are doing. Everything I mentioned above is working swimmingly. The functionality is there.

The relevant front-end is this:

```
 @{ int index = 0;}
            @foreach (var part in Model.PartInfoList)
            {
            <tr class="row table-bordered">
                <td class="col-4">
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="OldPartIDList" value="@part.PART_ID" name="OldPartIDList"/> @*This holds the "old" part ID's so the order can still be looked up when the user wants to change the part ID.*@
                    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" asp-for="NewPartIDList" value="@part.PART_ID" id="@part.PART_ID" name="NewPartIDList[@index]" onchange="HighlightField(this)" />
                    @*The id here is used to determine if the field should be highlighted or not.*@
                    <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="NewPartIDList[index]"></span>
                </td>
                <td class="col-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" asp-for="PartNumberList" value="@part.PART_NUMBER" id="@part.PART_NUMBER" name="PartNumberList[@index]" onchange="HighlightField(this)" />
                    @*The id here is used to determine if the field should be highlighted or not.*@
                    <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="PartNumberList[index]"></span>
                </td> 
                <td class="col-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" asp-for="QuantityList" value="@part.QUANTITY" id="@part.QUANTITY" name="QuantityList[@index]" onchange="HighlightField(this)" />
                    @*The id here is used to determine if the field should be highlighted or not.*@
                    <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="QuantityList[index]"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            index++;
            }
```

The lists are declared as such:

```
[DisplayName("Part ID"), BindProperty, Required]
        //[Range(1, 999999999, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a number between 1 and 999,999,999.")]
        [ResubmitSampleCenterOrderValidatorClass(FieldOptions.PART_ID, 1, 999999999, null)]
        public List<int> NewPartIDList { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Part Number"), BindProperty, Required]
        //[StringLength(48, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a part number.")]
        //[ResubmitSampleCenterOrderValidatorClass(FieldOptions.PART_NUMBER, 1, 999999999, PartNumberArray: PartNumberList.ToArray())]
        public List<string> PartNumberList { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Quantity"), BindProperty, Required]
        //[Range(1, 99999, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a number between 1 and 99,999.")]
        [ResubmitSampleCenterOrderValidatorClass(FieldOptions.QUANTITY, 1, 99999, null)]
        public List<int> QuantityList { get; set; }
```

The comments are what I've been trying. More on that later.

The Problem: Validation, on the part number input fields specifically. I cannot use

```
[StringLength(48, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a part number.")]
```

because the code will try to convert the string list to a string and that obviously can't happen. I just want to:
1) Make sure each part # cannot exceed 48 characters.
2) Have the error show up below that exact input field and NOT the others (This is actually an issue with the part ID and quantity fields as well, but I care more about the part # fields right now.)

Things I've tried:
As you can see from the comments above, I tried normal validation and it did not work for the above reasons. I then decided to go to the custom validation route:

```
public class ResubmitSampleCenterOrderValidatorClass: ValidationAttribute
    {
        public FieldOptions FieldDescriptor { get; set; }
        public int MinLength { get; set; }
        public int MaxLength { get; set; }
        public List<string> PartNumberList { get; set; }
        public string[] PartNumberArray { get; set; }

        public ResubmitSampleCenterOrderValidatorClass(FieldOptions FieldDescriptor, int MinLength, int MaxLength, string[] PartNumberArray)
        {
            this.FieldDescriptor = FieldDescriptor;
            this.MinLength = MinLength;
            this.MaxLength = MaxLength;
            this.PartNumberArray = PartNumberArray;
            PartNumberList = new List<string>();
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            switch(FieldDescriptor)
            {
                case FieldOptions.PART_NUMBER:
                    break;  
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

FieldOptions is just an enum, of which PART_NUMBER is 1. Anyways, I couldn't find a way to pass the string list into the custom validator because it isn't and cannot be static. I also couldn't find a way to get my numbers out of value for the part ID and quantity, but that's a separate issue.

I also put indexes on the name attributes for my input fields on the front end, hoping that could eventually lead to a solution. It was a trick I used in a JS/jQuery app I wrote a few years ago to do something very similar. Is there a way to access specific elements from the back-end, so I could just iterate through each one of them and validate them myself?

I have googled and googled, but I can't find anyone else with this issue. Maybe I haven't found the magic search words yet. I feel that if my part # validation woes are solved, I can use that solution on the problems I'm having with the other two fields.

All ideas are welcome! Let me know if you need more clarification! Thank you and have a fantastic day!

EDIT: More information on the syntax error I get when I try to pass

```
public List<string> PartNumberList { get; set; }
```

to the custom validator class. The class itself is found above. The syntax error reads:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'ReviewOrderModel.PartNumberList'.

Comment: `IsValid(object value` did you check what is "value" in this case, im pretty sure its your List<string> and after you cast it, is easy to validate

Comment: And for easy validation of collections i would use : `List<MyObject>` instead of `List<string>`, and give `MyObject` a property of type string with an `ValidationAttribute`

Comment: Thank you for the responses!! Do you have any example code or a doc link for your second response? As for the first response, I got a syntax error I could not get around when trying to send the List<string> to the custom validator due to the list not being static. I don't think the part # list can be static because an order could have anywhere from 1 to infinity parts.

Comment: `I got a syntax error I could not get around when trying to send the List<string> to the custom validator due to the list not being static.` Can you clarify more about the error and the issue, so that we can understand and troubleshoot the issue better.

Comment: I edited my OP with the syntax error. Thank you!!

Comment: `[ResubmitSampleCenterOrderValidatorClass(FieldOptions.PART_NUMBER, 1, 999999999, PartNumberArray: PartNumberList.ToArray())]` What is the actual scenario that requires passing current property (of your model) to custom validation attribute? Besides, if you'd like to get other properties of your model within custom validation attribute, you can try `validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType().GetProperty("PART_ID")`.

Comment: I dynamically create text inputs based on a return from the database. The user can then modify those text inputs, and they get submitted to the back-end for submission back to the database (if they have changed). I need a way to validate those inputs, is all. I have something that works in place now, but it is far from ideal. The problem is that I need a way to pass the part number values from the page model to the custom validator without getting the aforementioned syntax error.